# HTML page, load 10 items, then wait for scroll and load more

Tags: html, jquery, scroll

I have a list of so many items that loading them all at the time is very uncomfortable and takes a long time. I would like to implement a script that loads only 10 items and waits for scroll to load more. However I have no idea how to code it.

This is how my page looks:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    {% for i in range(data|length) %}
    <div class="re-container">
        <div class="re-container-item">
            <div class="re-item">
                <image class="re-img" src="{{url_for('static', filename='img/' + data.UNIQUE_RE_NUMBER[i].replace('/', '-') + '.jpg')}}" onerror="if (this.src != 'static/img/default.jpg') this.src = 'static/img/default.jpg';"></image>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="re-container-item">
            <div class="re-item">
                <p>{{ data.LOCATION[i] }}</p>
                <p class="re-date"> {{ data.MIN_DATE[i] }}  -  {{ data.MAX_DATE[i] }} </p>
            </div>
            <div class="re-item">
                <p>{{ data.ADDRSS[i] }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="re-item">
                <p><a class="article-title" href="{{url_for('/dashapp/', ure=data.UNIQUE_RE_NUMBER[i])}}">{{data.UNIQUE_RE_NUMBER[i]}}</a></p>
                <p class="re-price">{{data.RE_PRICE[i]}}</p>
                <hr>
            </div>
            <div class="re-item">
                <p>{{data.RE_INFO[i]}}</p>
            </div>
            {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
                <div class="re-item">
                    <form action="{{ url_for('saved') }}" method="POST">
                        <input type="hidden" value="{{ data.LOCATION[i] }}" name="location">
                        <input type="hidden" value="{{ data.UNIQUE_RE_NUMBER[i] }}" name="unique">
                        <input type="hidden" value="{{ data.ADDRSS[i] }}" name="address">
                        <input type="hidden" value="{{ data.RE_INFO[i] }}" name="info">
                        <input type="hidden" value="{{ data.RE_HREF[i] }}" name="href">
                        <input type="hidden" value="{{ data.TYP_ID[i] }}" name="typ">
                        <input type="hidden" value="{{ data.RE_POLOHA[i] }}" name="poloha">
                        <input type="hidden" value="{{ data.RE_DRUH[i] }}" name="druh">
                        <input type="hidden" value="{{ data.RE_TYP[i] }}" name="re-typ">
                        <input type="hidden" value="" name="dispozice">
                        <input type="hidden" value="" name="f_druh">
                        <input type="hidden" value="" name="pplocha">
                        <input type="hidden" value="" name="plocha">
                        <input type="hidden" value="" name="l_druh">
                        <input type="hidden" value="" name="site">
                        <input type="hidden" value="{{ data.MIN_DATE[i] }}" name="min_d">
                        <button class="re-button" type="submit">Save</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            {% endif %}
            <div class="re-item">
                <p>Poloha domu/vily: {{data.RE_POLOHA[i]}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="re-item">
                <p>Druh domu/vily: {{data.RE_DRUH[i]}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="re-item">
                <p>Typ domu/vily: {{data.RE_TYP[i]}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="re-item">
                {% if data.RE_HREF[i] != None %}
                    <a href="{{data.RE_HREF[i]}}">More here</a>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Does anyone have some suggestion?

Comment: I researched but havent come across this term, I was probably using the wrong words to describe my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the loading attribute in HTML. Just like below.

```
<img src="niceCats.jpg" loading="lazy">
```

I would advise you to read [this](https://css-tricks.com/native-lazy-loading/) aricle that CSSTrick put up on their page. Note this attribute is not supported on any safari version for IOS.

Comment: Answers should demonstrate a solution or provide information from the linked reference. See [answer].